# Jenkins - aggregate test results (SonarQube/JUnit) from multiple projects

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am currently working on a project which consists of several applications which in our infrastructure are tested with SonarQube and JUnit. For the moment I receive test reports for each subproject (application) separately.

My question is : what tools or solutions do you use to generate a report across multiple independent Maven projects to aggregate the test results generated by JUnit / Maven / Surefire ?

For the moment I came across SonarQube Governance plugin, however I would like to know the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The Governance plugin ($) is the only solution to aggregate projects. However, if you're talking about aggregating multiple test reports within a single project, that functionality is native in SonarQube 6.2. Further, for projects with sub-projects, the aggregation of sub-project data should happen naturally in the parent project.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution for multi-module maven projects. It might be a simple configuration error on my part, but the surefire-reports from the modules in my project are never picked up in the sonar report. Does the 'sonar.junit.reportsPath' property require a single directory? If so, any solutions to aggregate the individual reports for Sonar?